# On page load, add a class to an element in an Angularjs ng-repeat based on the value of a json object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a series of buttons that populate through a json object. When a user clicks a button, it changes the color (we will call this the chosen color) through `ng-class` (as a bootstrap class) and if the toggled button is clicked again, it goes back to is default color.

Now what I want to do is on page load, set the chosen color on each button where an `item.SelectedId` equals the specific `item.Home/AwayTeamId`. To reiterate, if a person has previously made selections, the `item.SelectedId` will be a non-zero number which is either `item.Home/AwayTeamId` and the button which they selected will be set to the chosen color.

I've tried to implement the logic in the code below, but I'm not having any luck. In fact, the buttons won't toggle at all. I wonder if someone can look at my code and see if they can provide some advice. Thanks.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-horizontal" data-ng-repeat="item in event.Events">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <button type="button" class="btn form-control"
                    data-ng-class="[pickChosen == 1 || checkIfChosen(item.SelectedId, item.homeTeamId, 1) ? 'btn-success' : 'btn-default']"
                    data-ng-disabled="item.Locked === 1"
                    data-ng-click="buttonToggle($index, 1)">
                <span class="hidden">{{item.homeTeamId}}</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <button type="button" class="btn form-control"
                    data-ng-class="[pickChosen == 2 || checkIfChosen(item.SelectedId, item.awayTeamId, 2) ? 'btn-success' : 'btn-default']"
                    data-ng-disabled="item.Locked === 1"
                    data-ng-click="buttonToggle($index, 2)">
                <span class="hidden">{{item.awayTeamId}}</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular:

```
app.controller('dashController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.buttonToggle = function (index, buttonNumber) {
        if (buttonNumber === this.pickChosen) {
            this.pickChosen = 0;
            picks.splice(index, 1);
        } else {
            this.pickChosen = buttonNumber;
        }
    };
    $scope.checkIfChosen = function(selId, teamId, buttonNumber) {
        if (selId === teamId) {
            this.pickChosen = buttonNumber;
        } else {
            this.pickChosen = 0;
        }
    };
});
```

Example json object:

```
[{"EventId":xxxxxxxx,
 "HomeTeamId":832,
 "AwayTeamId":575,
 "Locked":1,
 "SelectedId":0
},
{...},
{...}]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you probably forgot to return value from checkIfChosen(), you have `pickChosen == 2 || checkIfChosen(item.SelectedId, item.awayTeamId, 2) ? ....`.

Also, `this` in controller methods points to the same thing which is the instance of the controller, no matter which button click it's fired by.